# ‘GitHub Copilot’ in vscode encountered an error

Tags: vscode-extensions, github-copilot

The error message in the output TAB is as follows：

```
[ERROR] [default] [2022-12-10T09:50:38.676Z] GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation failed: "command 'rest-client.fold-response' already exists"
```

This doesn't seem to affect my copilot use, but I still want to cancel the error message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENTTI.png)

Hope somebody could tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try signing out, copilot will prompt you to sign back in. Also, Have you updated to the latest release?

Comment: I logged out of Copilot as you said and logged back as prompted, but still got the same error, plus I did update Copilot to the latest version(v1.63.7601)

Comment: Please visit this doc to troubleshoot your issue: https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/troubleshooting-github-copilot/troubleshooting-github-copilot-in-visual-studio-code